# Would the blood of Immortal beings be dangerous?

Tags: biology, diseases, demons

I am currently writing a world with several very very old mammal adjacent beings. I’m wondering to what extent their blood could be a hazard if spilled or given? if say a demon with warm blood and mammalian features goes and donates blood, should/ could they be allowed to? how much damage could an ancient disease collection cause on the human race with just one liter of blood? assuming the disease is bloodborne and not airborne. does anyone have any knowledge on ancient diseases or how to build a world with one?

Comment: In many myths a lot of immortal beings (gods demons etc) blood has extremely protean powers, whole beings and new species spring whole and fully formed from their spilled blood, if your going with that then hell yes it's dangerous! someone pumps a little god blood into you and moments later you get ripped apart as a fully grown Gorgon grows near instantly inside you ripping you asunder as they spring forth into the world ;)

Comment: I doubt demons would be allowed to donate blood

Comment: to what extent do you consider ancient diseases to be different to modern ones?

Comment: "allowed" in what sense?  Do you mean "would the blood bank be willing to accept donations from a known ancient god"?

Comment: Do you want the blood to be dangerous? By that, I mean, would it make the plot more interesting, the characters more compelling, the setting more visceral or the theme more poignant?

Comment: @MS maybe they usually just get turned away and they have no idea, they the donation center is not accepting their bucket of blood they offer

Comment: @MS I mean does it have to be their blood?

Comment: In the 90s TV series X-Men there was an episode where someone is in need of blood transfer and Wolverine has to decide whether to donate his blood or not. On the one hand, his blood has supernatural healing powers that might save the receiver. On the other hand, Wolverine has a flashback about a previous time where he tried to donate his blood to someone, and the receiver died because they couldn't cope with this different blood.

Comment: How does your immortality work? If the blood of your immortal may contain ancient diseases, that means the person is actually susceptible to the disease (otherwise, the pathogen could not persist). That kind of immortality sounds awful, when the disease stays forever. But, if instead the person's cells are also protected, the blood should be clean.

Comment: Or maybe they're in a state of semi-decrepitude, never quite healing or dying from all the diseases they harbour. Disgusting creatures, unsanitary. @Chieron

Comment: What are 'mammal adjacent beings' please? Does that mean 'beings somewhat similar to mammals' or what?

Comment: If 'demon (anything)…, clearly a major part of this is magic… which makes the rules entirely your own.

Why might your beings' blood be a hazard, whether or not they had warm blood or mammalian features? 

All that aside, with the right disease - and this is your world, with your rules - one litre of blood could wipe out the world.

However, what is this 'ancient' disease? How did it mot anciently kill the carriers (demons?)? 

Isn't 'how to build a world with one' your job alone? Aren't you Asking SE Members to do it for you?

Answer (score 13):

Just because a disease is *old* does not necessarily make it a problem. Rather, the issue is *extinct* diseases, which the human immune system no longer protects against. These could be a major problem—*if they're present.*

Unlike with melting permafrost and the like, your hypothetical immortals have (presumably) been living among humans more or less continuously. Thus, they are likely to have the same diseases as humans.

If an immortal *does* carry an ancient disease, their proximity to humans means that the human population is continually exposed to it, a sort of Typhoid Mary-esque situation.

Also, while I'm at it, time for a **Frame Challenge!**

As you describe them, your immortals are not human; they just look similar. As a result, they should not be able to donate blood. Without blood donation, the only way for bloodborne diseases to be transferred is if the blood spilled on someone, which is unlikely given that we are talking about powerful immortal beings.

Comment: *"the issue is extinct diseases, which the human immune system no longer protects against. These could be a major problem—if they're present"* diseases that by definition have never been extinct because they have always had this immortal host to swim around in and from there presumably (sans any other details to contraindicate) sally forth into other hosts, unless the immortal being has been a recluse or frozen in ice for a few million years any disease they might host will be ubiquitous and everyone will have evolved to live with it, won't even know they have it or it's as mild as a cold.

Comment: [ponders] or they're immune and it can't infect them no matter how much of it you expose them to, there's a few very very rare cases like that with aids and (we think) black death, it can't get into the cells because none of its 'keys' fiit their locks .. the only way a lethal disease in such an immortal host (unless they don't live around people) could not become reasonably harmless by forcing the evolution of the population is if it can only be contracted in extremely rare circumstance, a blood transfusion could qualify for that of course..

Comment: *"a blood transfusion could qualify for that of course"* .. though it may be hard to justify how a disease that difficult to contract would have evolved and survived in the first place.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of modern immune systems (like the ones humans have) that they're adaptive. So if it meets something new it can (given 5 or so days) come up with a way to kill it. If anything an ancient disease should be millions of years behind in the evolutionary arms race and be easily defeated by the immune system. (Lots of virus evolution is about evading the immune system)

Comment: *"Unlike with melting permafrost and the like, your hypothetical immortals have (presumably) been living among humans more or less continuously."* << There is a lot of humor that can be contained in the "more or less" of this sentence! If many demons are tens of millions of years old, maybe some of them occasionally take a few thousands or hundreds of thousands of years away from the mortal world for napping or meditation or because they temporarily lost their way in an ethereal labyrinth. Homo sapiens is "only" 300000 years old. And diseases mutate fast.

Comment: @Stef Good point! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @RichardTingle but the ancient disease has not posed any evolutionary pressure for a long time, so the immune system's originally successful response to the disease possibly is no longer active (because something mutated and that mutation had no negative side anymore, maybe was even positive in fighting some other disease).

Comment: @Chieron my point is that modern adaptive immune systems don't have specific responses to specific diseases (and they dont care if something is harmful), they just try to kill anything that is "not self". Now a virus can try to hide to avoid the immune system. But a random, ancient disease wouldn't know how to do that and wouldn't stand a chance. Remember no evolution happens between you being infected by a cold you've never interacted with this month and you being immune next month. You might have a spike while everyone gets this mild disease at once (although I doubt it) but thats it

Answer (score 8):

In general you cannot get a blood donation from another species. It is already [expletive] complicated between members of the same species. Sure, medical tech made it so that giving or receiving blood nowadays seems like nothing special, but the blood you give goes through a lot of treatment to make it usable.

There has been some research in the past about receiving blood from other animals. That's called [xenotransfusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenotransfusion) and it seems like pig blood is just compatible enough with human blood, though it still needs a lot of treatment - it's just cheaper and safer to stick to human donours only for now.

So in a world where demons are a part of society and have compatible enough blood, the only justifications to use demon blood on a human would be:

- granting demonic powers (if that happens)
- scientific experimentation
- or the science and techbology have evolved enough that it is possible to remove whatever antigens demon blood has relative to human blood.

Also, if done methodically, any blood being donated will be triaged in order to discard blood bags that have infectious agents in them. After all, even decades ago donated blood containing certain agents like HIV got discarded after being tested for it.

Comment: A fourth justification could perhaps be "they didn't know the donated blood wasn't human". I'm not sure they test to make sure the blood is human, since that can kinda be assumed anyway... though I suspect the blood typing would show that up, perhaps? Also, they only test for about ten diseases in the US, so an unknown bloodborne disease wouldn't have a test for it. Frustratingly, since I've lived in both the US and UK, I'm forbidden from donating in either, since both places have endemic diseases that the other doesn't test for.

Comment: *"Sure, medical tech made it so that giving or receiving blood nowadays seems like nothing special, but the blood you give goes through a lot of treatment to make it usable."* << It's even worse that that. It's more "a lot of tests" than "a lot of treatment". Blood banks don't "treat" blood from individual A in order to make it suitable for individual B; instead, they test the blood of all donors and receivers, and pick donor-receiver pairs that look like a match, and then perform a crosstest to be sure they're really a match.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly common trope when it comes to immortals donating blood/organs/etc is the material in question being some degree of self-replicating (partially explaining how the creature can be immortal, since the cells are perfectly copying without transcription errors and/or aggressively weeding out issues). In some settings, that can result in powers, transformation into another of the immortal beings, or raging cancer as the material constantly wars with the already replicating human cells.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of immortals and disease is interesting, because it suggests a virus could survive indefinitely in one host, without needing any mechanism for transmission.

You could imagine an immortal who's lived for however many years with a chronic blood infection, analogous to hepatitis or herpes.
If the host sheds the virus, then they'll be a Typhoid Mary, and any population they live in will gradually gain herd immunity.

But instead of shedding, you can imagine that the virus' evolution, in its battle with the host's immune system, has long ago optimised out any features which enabled its transmission. It would now exist in a steady state in the immortal's blood, harmless to others except in extreme scenarios such as blood transfusion.

Then, on entering the blood of a mortal with no immunity, it might rage out of control, rapidly killing the recipient without spreading further. This would be a stable equilibrium: there would never be an epidemic, so mortals would never develop immunity.

Answer (score 0):

### Immortals Effectively Have a Different Blood Type

If immortals still have antibodies for many diseases long gone maybe their blood causes a reaction like those to the antibodies of differently typed blood.  Maybe there's be no issue for contact but transfusion would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the complications of cross-species blood transfusions. You want the blood of immortals to play a role in your world, so a role it shall play.

### Immortal blood grants immortality, and that is dangerous

10 years on, and the science is still not clear. What is clear is that the Red Cross received a strange blood donation. It failed to match any existing blood group systems. The entire donation should have been sent to the lab for further processing, but some tech used the blood to spike a bunch of AB neg bags. He claims an alien was communicating with him on an online forum and told him to do it.

We have been monitoring the recipients of the spiked blood. Most of them are accounted for. No confirmed deaths. The oldest just celebrated her 120th birthday, and she now looks younger than she did 50 years ago. Rumors are beginning to spread. An experimental cure for aging has worked. In the face of the relentless march of time, people are frantically trying to find this cure.

Word must have gotten out about the spiked donations, because there has been an unprecedented uptick in blood thefts. I wish it were just from the blood bank. Rising reports of elderly gangs, kidnapping, slashing, and licking people who look too young for their age. They say they got the idea on an online forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a self-solving problem. Immortal blood cells, and worse, immortal white blood cells, are going to be a nightmare to the new host's body. It would lead to a whole host of problems, from anaphylactic shock, to extreme autoimmune reaction, and up to leukemia,  marrow cancer or even being literally eaten from the inside by immortal white blood cells.